# Problem with producing valid forecasts

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a weird problems with producing good forecasts with R and the forecast package.

The data I use can be found here: http://pastebin.com/2gwyVYrj

Sample code I used:

```
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)
library(xts)

#TIME and VALUE fields (UNORDERED and few missing values). TIME is in YYYYMMDDHH format as character
data <- read.csv("data.csv", sep="|", header=TRUE)

#Gets the values
vals <- data$VALUE

#Parses time to POSIXct format
time <- parse_date_time(data$TIME, orders="ymdh")

#Create time series
timeSeries <- xts(vals,time)

#Fit ets model to data

model <- ets(timeSeries)

#I want 168h step ahead prediction so

forecasted_values <- forecast(model,h=168)

#My goal is to write the predicted values back to file so I need the      

#corresponding time stamps for the prediction

#I found this method somewhat works last timestamp (max + 3600) to 168h ahead (max + 3600*168)

prediction_time <- seq(from=(parse_date_time(max(subset_data$TIME_ID), orders="ymdh")+3600),
                         to=(parse_date_time(max(subset_data$TIME_ID), orders = "ymdh")+3600*168),
                     by="hour")
```

I think the predicted values are in `forecasted_values$mean` because that has the correct length (168 as I wanted). But it has a constant value...

Any ideas what went wrong and how could I get new dataframe with correct forecasted values and their corresponding (future) timestamps in the same "yyymmddhh" format?

EDIT:

Changing the model to ARIMA didn't help either.

```
model <- auto.arima(timeSeries)

#168h prediction

forecasted_values <- forecast(model,h=168)

#not a valid forecast!
plot(forecasted_values$mean)
```

Comment: See http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/flat-forecasts/